# Авторизация в СУБД MySQL в связке с [WPF + MVVM + Entity Framework]

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Есть приложение WPF, разделенное на три части согласно паттерну MVVM. Приложение работает с БД MySql средствами Entity Framework 6. 
Появилась необходимость авторизации пользователей в приложении. Каждый пользователь - это не просто запись в таблице Users базы данных, он также является пользователем на уровне СУБД (сделал так для разграничения прав на определенные таблицы и для записи в логи). 
Так вот, как реализовать следующий функционал в соответствии с MVVM:

- при запуске выводить окно авторизации, где пользователь вводит свои логин и пароль;
- потом по введеным логину и паролю генерировать строку подключения, по которой и будет подключаться контекст EF к базе данных. Важно делать это именно таким образом, чтобы можно было в коде быстро и удобно передавать эту строку в контекст;
- дальше пытаться уже, собсно, авторизоваться в СУБД и, если авторизация успешна, работать под этим пользователем (в БД есть триггеры, пишущие логи изменений, в которых много раз используется функция CURRENT_USER);
- хранить строку подключения где-то в файле крайне нежелательно, т.к. это плохо скажется на безопасности да и на скорости.

Comment: как вариант завести отдельную таблицу для хранения логин-хэшпароля и выделить доступ одному пользователю БД доступ на чтение из этой таблицы, ну а дальше программа под этим пользователем сверяет данные из этой таблицы...

Comment: Спасибо, но нет. Тогда в триггерах вызываемая функция CURRENT_USER() будет возвращать того пользователя, под которым авторизовалось в СУБД само приложение.

Comment: вы не совсем поняли. Под общим пользователем только проверяются данные логин:пароль и все, если ОК, то формируете строку подключения и соединяетесь с базой под данными конкретного чела.